# Basis functions for a Galerkin procedure

Tags: mathematical-physics, orthogonality, computational-mathematics, orthogonal-polynomials, galerkin-methods

For a Galerkin procedure, I am trying to construct a set of linerly independent functions $\{\varphi_n\}_{n = 1}^N$ satisfying
$$
\varphi_n(0) = 0, ~~ \varphi_n'(1) = 0,
$$
for all $n \geq 1$.

A trivial set satisfying the above boundary considitions is
$$
\varphi_n(t) = t^n (1 - t)^{n + 1},
$$
which are linearly independent: the Wronskian vanishes only at $t = 0, 0.5, 1$.

Are there other families of $\varphi_n$? Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Comment: That family is trivially l.i. because all of the polynomials have different degrees.

Comment: Definitely right! I realized it a bit later. Are there any other families?

Answer (score 2):

The family

$$
\psi_n(x)=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}\sin\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi  x\right)
$$
may work for you.

**Edit**

If $\{f_n\}$ is a set of differentiable linearly independent functions that $t \not \in \text{span}(\{\varphi_n\})$ and satisfies $f'_n(1)\neq 0$, you can define the linearly independent family $\{\varphi_n\}$ by
$$
\varphi_n(t)=\frac{1}{f_n'(1)} (f_n(t)-f_n(0))-t,
$$
which satisfies $\varphi_n(0)=\varphi_n'(1)=0$.

Comment: Maybe you meant $\varphi_n(t) = \sin\left(\frac{2n + 1}{2}\pi t\right)$?

Comment: $\psi_n'(x)=\cos(2\pi n x)$, am I right? Then $\psi_n'(1)=\cos(2 \pi n)=1$.

Comment: I am so sorry to have a typo in the second boundary condition. It should be $\varphi_n'(1) = 0$.

Comment: It's ok, maybe now it would help :)

Comment: I have checked, the Wronskian is 0 only when $t = 0$ and $t = 1$.

Comment: Good! I will think in another family. I'll let you know.

Comment: I added a general answer.

Comment: Thanks! Are $\varphi_n$ linearly independent for arbitrary $f_n$?